# jquerymobile popup selects list item on close button

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-popup

I have a jQueryMobile site that does like what most do; there is a list of items and when one item is selected, a popup is displayed with some additional information about the item.  There are 2 buttons at the bottom of the popup: one submits a form that is contained in the popup and then closes the popup and one simply dismisses the popup.  When either of those 2 buttons are tapped, the row in the list view that is underneath the popup is selected.

This behavior doesn't exist when using the device emulation mode of Google Chrome, so doing any kind of DOM inspection is almost impossible.

Any suggestions are welcome; either how to solve the problem or how to debug it.

-Matthew

Comment: Maybe try adding a e.stopPropagation or return false on the click handler?

Comment: Popup is dismissible `data-dismissible="false"` or not?

Comment: data-dismissable="false", yes.

Comment: tried e.preventDefault() on the button clicks.  No joy

Comment: I tried simply deselecting all elements in the underlying <ul /> (which actually means the <a /> elements that are just inside the <li /> elements by removing the ui-btn-active class.  That works perfectly in the emulator, but all it does on the actual phone is to deselect the previous row, but keep the row right under the button active.  I've actually got my "deselect" code in the afterClose event of the popup.

Comment: Maybe you need to apply an overlay underneath popup that covers whole screen to absorb any click event.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?  FWIW, using e.stopPropagation and e.stopImmediatePropagation doesn't work either.  I tried adding a .listview("refresh") after removing the ui-button-active class and that didn't work either.

Comment: after talking to the project stakeholders, we decided to use a different UI metaphor and simply navigate to a different page instead of popping up a dialog. This gives us more visible room, too.